Python: Alternatives to numpy or tensorflow tensordot for large matrices
I am looking for more efficient solutions to calculating a tensor product between large matrices in Python. Specifically, I want to calculate a tensor product such as $H \otimes I$ for two matrices H and I. However, for large matrices of dimension 156 and larger my kernel crashes. I am quite new to coding, so there likely could be an obvious solution I'm missing.
I have created a reproducible example:
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
A = np.random.random((200,200))
B = np.random.random((200,200))
C = tf.tensordot(A,B,axes=0)

Tensorflow gives a warning 2024-05-07 10:57:10.174373: W external/local_tsl/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:83] Allocation of 12800000000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
Indicating that I need to find a more memory-efficient way of calculating this. Numpy does not give a similar warning, but I assume it is the same underlying problem.
Doing this with much smaller matrices do not cause the same problems.
What alternatives do I have to calculate large tensor products of matrices?

For any physicists out there, I found out the correct thing to do here is using Kronecker products, not tensor products. This correctly gives a block-matrix.

According to the docs, when a and b are matrices (order 2), the case axes=0 gives the outer product, a tensor of order 4.
So the size of the result is 200 * 200 * 200 * 200 floats (12.8 GB, as Tensorflow warns). This is not a problem of memory efficiency, just the size of the requested operation.

Probably good idea to case A and B to float32, like A = A.astype(np.float32), unless precision is really important.

This would make a lot of sense, thanks! @Mercury would this decrease the memory needed to store the variable? My actual matrices has complex entries. Could I convert both the real and imaginary parts to float32?

Yes, it would decrease the memory. But if you are working with complex numbers, it would naturally consume 64 bits (32+32) = 8 bytes per element; (200^4) * 8, still 12.8GB. However that is still a lot better than the complex version of the default np.float64, which would consume 128 bits = 16 bytes ~25GB. (np.float64 -> np.complex128, while np.float32 -> np.complex64.)
